# Using angular $http request to find specific array value

Tags: http

I'm using angular to make a $http get request for some data (I removed the URL to make it easier to read here):

```
var app = angular.module('pointsource', []);

app.controller('UserProfile', ['$http', function($http){

     var profile = this;

     profile.bio = [ ];

     $http.get('URL').success(function(data){

          profile.bio = data;

     });

}]);
```

Said data is always random and is organized like this:

```
"person": {
    "gender": "female",
    "first-name": "Yvonne",
    "family-name": "Young",
    "pictureURL": "/assets/img/female2.png"
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to add specfic classes to an html element based on if the gender returns male or female. Any ideas what else I need to add to my controller for it to do this? Thanks!

Here's my failed attempt:

```
var app = angular.module('pointsource', []);
app.controller('UserProfile', ['$http', function($http){
var profile = this;

profile.bio = [ ];

$http.get('http://applicant.pointsource.us/api/testUser/57869704f62a2d8f3c05da99').success(function(data){
  profile.bio = data;
  if (profile.bio.person.gender == 'male') {
      $('#gender').addClass('male');
  }
});
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery to make DOM changes in an angular controller it is usually an indication that you are doing it the wrong way. A better approach would be the ngClass directive (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) and bind this to the value in the controller.

```
<div ng-controller="UserProfile as profile>
    <div id="gender" ng-class="profile.bio.person.gender"></div>
</div>
```

and in the controller you don't need to make any reference to the DOM element at all:

```
app.controller('UserProfile', ['$http', function($http){
var profile = this;

profile.bio = [ ];

    $http.get('http://applicant.pointsource.us/api/testUser/57869704f62a2d8f3c05da99'    ).success(function(data){
  profile.bio = data;

    });
}]);
```

Have a look at https://plnkr.co/edit/kfDtUGTHbmBtmd3BJA6j?p=preview for a simple example.